# can i use angular8 components in angularJS(1.x) as a node module?

Tags: angularjs, angular8

i am working on a angular 8 application , when user clicks on a button it should redirect to a vendor portal which is completely a different webapp (diff Url), when user redirect to vendor page , user should see the same header ,footer and navigation what i have in my web application. but the vendor application is on angularJS(1.x).

so my question is can i convert my angular header,footer,navigation(navigation consists of some SSO logic) into node modules and ask my vendor to use them in their angularJS(1.x) applicatoin?

if we cannot use angular8 components in angularJS (1.x), can some one suggest the better approach ?

update:
can we convert the Angular8 project/component into a standalone JS file and ask the vendor to load the JS file in their application ?
so this JS should contain the logic to replace/inject with in their page.
for ex: we ask the vendor to create a  element in their page, in our JS file we need to look to "custom-header" Id and replace with our content ?

so can we write custom code in our Angular8 application and export it as a standalone JS file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't straightforward use Angular components on angularJs.

But you can convert your ng components or ng application to Web Components using `@angular/elements`.

Web Components are framework-agnostic, meaning they can be used outside the context of the framework used to create them. Pretty much all modern browsers are prepared to deal with them and there are polyfills to use if you want to support more browsers.

Detailed info on Angular elements: https://angular.io/guide/elements

And here's a guide on how to do it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-angular-6-custom-elements-web-components-c88814dc6e0a/

**edit:** changed the guide on how do it, the other one wasn't so good.

Comment: can we use the routing in webcomponents . for ex: to comeback to mywebapp from vendor application

Comment: I'm not even sure if you can use angular routing at all, but if you can it will only work inside that element (assuming it includes a router-outlet. to go back to your page you'll need to use a full URL, either in an anchor or via js when handling an event output by that element.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use angular8 component in angularjs.because this frameworks very different from each other.

Comment: can we convert angular8 shared component(header) into a JS file and use it in angular 1.x ?